# How to branching and merging any project in Xcode - MAC OS X?

Tags: xcode8

I am new in Apple Development. I am using Xcode latest version 8.

Having query which open source or payed tools are best for branching and merging any project/application in Xcode?

Is there any documents available for guidance or is there any way to do branching and merging by using Xcode?

Currently we are using SVN but for that we have to merging and branching in windows OS not in MAC OS.

Can anyone please help and guide and explain about is the industry standard way?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

`svn` and `git` are both available on Mac.

For example:

> ~ pmills$ git --version
>
> git version 2.11.0 (Apple Git-81)
>
> ~ pmills$ svn --version
>
> svn, version 1.9.4 (r1740329)

Comment: Do you have any user guide link? Can you please share if you have. Thanks in advance

Comment: Open a terminal window and type `svn help`.  That will give you a list of the commands you can get help on and also a link to the Apache site.